# Derivative of a product with respect to the multiplier and generalization

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Say I have a differentiable function

$$
f(x) = f(g(x),h(x)) = g(x)h(x)
$$

If I compute $df/dx$ I can apply the product rule, but what about

$$
\frac{df}{dg} = ?
$$

what can I do in this case?

The only attempt is this one

$$
\frac{df}{dg} = \frac{df}{dx} \frac{dx}{dg} = \left(g'(x)h(x) + g(x)h'(x) \right) \frac{dx}{dg}
$$

Is $dg/dx = \frac{1}{g'(x)}$? If it is true then

$$
\frac{df}{dg} = h(x) + g(x)\frac{h'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$

How can I generalize this to the generic

$$
f(x) = f(g(x),h(x))?
$$

Thank you.

Comment: I'd probably need to add that $h,g$ are differentiable and $g'(x) \neq 0$

Comment: **Never** use the same name for different functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, let's rewrite a little. You have two different things labelled "f", which is a problem. What's really going on is that there's a function $H$:

$$
M(a, b) = a b
$$
and 
$$
f(x) = M(g(x), h(x)).
$$

Now applying the chain rule is comparatively obvious: the derivatives of $M$ with respect to its first and second arguments are easy to find:
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial a}(a, b) = b \\
\frac{\partial M}{\partial b}(a, b) = a.
$$
So 
\begin{align}
\frac{d f}{dx} 
&= \frac{\partial M}{\partial a}(g(x), h(x)) \frac{d g(x)}{d x} + \frac{\partial M}{\partial b}(g(x), h(x)) \frac{d h(x)}{d x} \tag{1}\\
&= h(x) \frac{d g(x)}{d x} + g(x) \frac{d h(x)}{d x} \\
&= h(x) g'(x) + g(x) h'(x)
\end{align}

As for the more general case, where the function $M$ is some arbitrary function rather than just multiplication, the formula for that case is what's shown in equation (1) above.

General principle: never do what the physicists do all the time, writing things like 
$$
f(z)= f(x(z), y(z))
$$
where $f$ has two different meanings, until you're completely confident with using the chain rule as I've done above. At that point, it'll start to seem natural (but you'll still probably screw up sometimes).

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your process because since both $h$ and $g$ depend on $x$ assuming, for example $g$ is invertible we would have that $h$ depend on $g$ as well. Also I was asking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$ not with respect to $x$, what you wrote down is essential the chain rule, unless I'm missing something in the explanation. Also you mention a function $H$ but you don't use it.

Comment: And what I'm telling you is that "df/dg" makes no sense, because $f$ is a function of a single variable. What you really want (even if you don't know it) is $\frac{\partial M} {\partial a}$ (evaluated at $(a, b) = (g(x), h(x))$). [I have, BTW, made a slight edit, replacing $a$ and $b$ in the later lines of my solution with $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ respectively]. As for your claim that "$h$ depends on $g$ as well," that's not exactly right. (Indeed, the notion of "depends on" isn't very precisely defined). $h$ may vary when $g$ varies, but $h$ is a function of a single variable, $x$.

Comment: I can see some sense in the formula I've derived though.

Comment: Wonderful --- then you don't need me. It looks like complete nonsense to me, but if it works for you to get the right answers, so be it. Mine has the advantage (to me) that I can prove it's correct, however, and that it generalizes very well. I've answered your first question ("but what about $df/dg$?"), and I guess my answer to the second ("Is $dg/dx = 1/g'(x)$?") is "No, because you meant to write $dx/dg$, and even that doesn't make sense except when $g$ is (at least locally) invertible." As for the third ("How can I generalize?"), you can't...unless you know that things are invertible.

Comment: And the real answer is "The general approach is exactly a careful application of the chain rule, which I've demonstrated above."

Comment: XD I didn't mean to say your approach is wrong, because as you said is proved to be correct, I wouldn't dare to argue that. But probably my problem is I don't use the differential notation correctly. Unless I state the problem more precisely I guess this is the max I can do.

Comment: I think we agree on this; often, a very clear expression of a problem actually solves the problem. (This happens frequently in probability problems, for instance.) The "dy/dx" notation is particularly prone to multiple interpretations and "puns", which makes it particular bad for beginners (and good for experts!), because it's not clear what any particular expression means unless (a) you're the author, or (b) you share the author's mindset.